# Keyboard is different height causing view to be resized incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I'm trying to adjust my collection view to be resized differently depending on the keyboard so it just occupies the space on the screen where the keyboard is not. However, when I push a view and come back it seems the keyboard has a different height. Regularly it has a height of 293 but when I push a view and come back it has a height of 336. This is too tall and causes my view to be cut off revealing what's underneath. Any ideas why this is the case?

I have the following code:

```
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardFrameEnd = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let convertedKeyboardFrameEnd = self.view.convert(keyboardFrameEnd, from: nil)
        let intersection = convertedKeyboardFrameEnd.intersection(listView.frame)
        if intersection.size.height > 0 {
            self.listView.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
                make.top.leading.trailing.equalTo(0)
                make.bottom.equalTo(-intersection.height)
            }
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `make.bottom.equalTo(-intersection.height + 45)` and it works to cover the area outside of the keyboard. But it feels weird to add a constant term when it seems that the keyboard height is wrong.

Comment: Not sure how you came up with this code but pretty complex for adjusting for keyboard presentation. This is a common operation. A simple google search for "UIView adjust constraints keyboard height" should offer better suggestions.

Comment: Hm, I think this is standard type of code for this operation. Basically I get the intersection between the keyboard and my view and set my view's constraints to be the bottom of that intersection. My problem here is that the keyboard size is different. It goes from 293 to 336 for some reason. I'm not sure what's causing the keyboard size to be like that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this lib: IQKeyboardManager

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).